# Do new laptop batteries require charge cycles before reaching full capacity?

Tags: battery-charging, batteries, laptop

I have purchased a new battery for my hp pavilion dv6500 laptop.

The description in the shop read that it should be a new battery.

Using Fedora OS, I did `inxi -Bxxx` to see some info on the battery and I see that its condition is 73%.

Does this mean it is a used battery or should I expect it will get better condition as advertised in the same seller description where I read that "it requires 4/5 full charge/discharge cycles to reach its fullest capacity"?

[image: inxi -Bxxx ouput]

Answer (score 2):

It is generally a good idea to go through a full charge - discharge cycle when replacing a battery. This is not to "initialize" the battery itself but to initialize the **battery monitoring system**.

In many devices the battery management circuits need to "learn" what the battery voltage is when the battery is fully charged and when it is (almost) empty. So I would fully charge the battery and then run inxi again and see what you get.

Do realize that Li-Ion batteries do degrade over time even if you do not use them. If the battery has been lying on a shelf for a year it might have lost some of its capacity even though it was never used and is considered "new".

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will check again with inxi to see if the info are different and will give you a feedback.

Comment: Factory should have at least done that once. New battery with 73% health is not a new battery.

Comment: @Jeroen3 *Factory should have at least done that once* Nope, the factory 1) cannot do that when the voltage detection circuit is in the laptop. 2) does not want to do that as it takes too much **time** making the process expensive. 3) Li-Ion cells are fabricated having a charge level of about 40% to 60% because that charge level makes them degrade the least over time. Fabricating batteries with a 100% charge level puts stress on the batteries and/or is too expensive as it takes time to charge them.

Comment: *New battery with 73% health is not a new battery.* Like I explained, it can be when it has been stored for a long time and your definition of "new" is "has not been used". But feel free to prove me wrong by showing some evidence that shows that your comment is correct and that I am indeed wrong.

Comment: I went through a complete discharge/recharge cycle. First thing: the `init` output did not change (I added it to my question). Secondly: I just watched a movie in the browser and, without having anything else opened, the battery percentage dropped from 100 to 35% in about 1hr. I can see that as I stopped watching the movie the rate of discharging has decreased, but, still, is this reasonable? The seller told me I can test it for up to 5 days and that they can substitute it if I'm not fine with my tests. As I am writing, I read 25% and it's been only 1hr and a half since I turned on the laptop.